# For IOS,how to make the separator visible for some cells while other not

Tags: ios

I try to use `setSeparatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNONE;`

And it works but I am disappointed because it lets all the separator disappear, this is not what I want. I want to have cell 1, 3 and 4 have separator, while cell 2 separator needs to be hidden. How can i do that?

Comment: is there any pattern to know that which cell should have separator and which cell should not..?

Comment: can i get upvote too dude any way thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Hide tableView's standard separator line
**First use**

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

You can Change hight/width/color/image of UIView for set your separatorLine.

**Add custom separator to add  UIView of 1px height in cell:**

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];/// change size as you need.
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];// you can also put image here
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

**and in index 2**

```
    Cell.separatorLineView.hidden = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SeperatorStyle` property is assigned to the `UITableView`. So for customization first of all set

```
[tableview setSeparatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone] 
//thus the default seperator will be hidden.
```

Now insert a view having width, the same as cell width, height 1, and color separator preferred color. thus by giving reference we can show or hide this seperatorView accordingly. Seems bulky, but simple.

Answer (score 0):

1. `setSeparatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNONE; //remove all separator`

2.the `contentView` of Cell call the method `addSubview` ,the subView is a image(line is bottom at a background image) or a view whose height is 1px.
View the subView as a separator .

3.design a property for a cell, then change the property in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` According to  the property, you can determine  if the separator is Hidden in method `awakeFromNib`